# Authentication methods supported by flink cli?

Tags: authentication, command-line-interface, apache-flink

What authentication methods can I use between the flink cli and the job manager?

Or what plugin APIs are available to drop in my own authentication solutions without hacking and rebuilding the cli and backend?

Answer (score 2):

The CLI communicates with the cluster via HTTP. You can configure SSL mutual authentication beween CLI and cluster [1]. If you need more sophisticated authentication or authorization options, the user documentation recommends to deploy a proxy in front of the cluster [1]. However, there is currently no possibility to extend the client [2] [3] with authentication so you will likely have to write your own client.

[1] https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/ops/security-ssl.html#external--rest-connectivity

[2] https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/8f8e35815c917616f98c13d056f20fefe36098f3/flink-clients/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/client/program/rest/RestClusterClient.java

[3] https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/8f8e35815c917616f98c13d056f20fefe36098f3/flink-runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/rest/RestClient.java

Comment: Anyone considered adding support to the client for some ubiquitous authen schemes to the infra.

Comment: I am not aware of any ongoing efforts. You may want to post a proposal to the user mailing list